# Deque implementation based on doubly linked list not working

Tags: c++, c, pointers, data-structures, struct

here is my code for deque implementation using doubly linked list. It is not working..can u get me some pointers on where i am going wrong. The pointers are not initialised and the code is getting stuck in the addqatend function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <Windows.h>

struct node
{
struct node *prev;
int data;
struct node *next;
};

struct queue
{
struct node *front;
struct node *rear;
};


void initqueue(struct queue *);
void addqatbeg(struct queue *,int);
void addqatend(struct queue *, int);
int delqatbeg(struct queue *);
int delqatend(struct queue *);
void delqueue(struct queue *);

int main()
{
struct queue a;
int i;

system("cls");
initqueue(&a);

addqatbeg(&a,11);
addqatbeg(&a,23);
addqatbeg(&a,-5);
addqatbeg(&a,45);

addqatend(&a,34);
addqatend(&a,78);

i = delqatbeg(&a);
if(i!=NULL)
    printf("item deleted from front:%d",i);
i = delqatbeg(&a);
if(i!=NULL)
    printf("item deleted from front:%d",i);
i = delqatend(&a);
if(i!=NULL)
    printf("item deleted from end:%d",i);
i = delqatend(&a);
if(i!=NULL)
    printf("item deleted from end:%d",i);

delqueue(&a);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

//initialise the queue
void initqueue(struct queue *q)
{
q->front = q->rear = NULL;
}

//add at the beginning of the queue
void addqatbeg(struct queue *q,int item)
{
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(temp == NULL)
    printf("queue is full\n");
//temp->data = item;
//temp->link = NULL;
if(q->front == NULL)
{
    q->rear = q->front = temp;
    q->front->prev = NULL;
    q->front->next = NULL;
    q->rear->next = NULL;
    q->rear->prev = NULL;
    return;
}


q->front->data = item;
q->front->next = temp;
q->front = temp;
q->front->prev = q->front;
//q->rear->next = q->front->next;
//q->front->prev = q->rear;
}

//add at the end of the queue
void addqatend(struct queue *q, int item)
{
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(temp == NULL)
    printf("queue is full\n");
if(q->front == NULL)
{
    q->rear = q->front = temp;
    q->front->prev = NULL;
    q->front->next = NULL;
    return;
}
while(q->front->next!=NULL)
    q->rear = q->front->next;
q->rear->data = item;
q->rear->next =temp;
q->rear = q->rear->next;
q->rear->prev = q->rear;
 }

//delete at the beginning of the queue
int delqatbeg(struct queue *q)
{
struct node *temp;
int item;
if(q->front ==NULL)
{
    printf("queue is empty:\n");
    return NULL;
}
item = q->front->data;
temp = q->front;
q->front = q->front->next;
free(temp);
return item;
 }

//delete at the end of the queue
 int delqatend(struct queue *q)
{
struct node *temp;
int item;
if(q->rear == NULL)
{
    printf("queue is empty\n");
    return NULL;
}
item = q->rear->data;
temp = q->rear;
q->rear = q->rear->prev;
free(temp);
return item;
}

//free the nodes
 void delqueue(struct queue *q)
{
struct node *temp;

if(q->front == NULL)
    return;
while(q->front!=NULL)
{
    temp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->next;
    free(temp);
}
}
```

Comment: So you expect us to comb through your code, understand it, find your error, debug your error, and re-code it for you? "Effort begets effort."

Comment: I am a newbie here.. so can u please help on this..i am also new to data structures

Comment: @jitendrakumar You will have to be more specific regarding the exact problem that you are facing. "It is not working..." does not help much. Tell us what part works and the exact point at which it hangs or gets stuck.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, it is getting stuck in the second function addatend in the while loop. It is stuck in a infinite loop and the pointers next, prev and data all seem to be uninitialised.

Comment: @jitendrakumar Now is a good time to learn how to debug your code. If any loop is getting stuck in while loop, it means that the termination condition is not being met. If you say that the pointers are not initialized, then back track and check till what part the code works as expected, preferably by using your debugger or atleast by outputting debug messages to your console.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, when i using two structs as in my code..how many pointers i have to initialise in each function. Shd i initilise all the pointers ie q->front->prev,q->front->next,q->rear->prev,q->rear->next.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

Ugh, that's a whole slew of includes. What language are you using? Make up your mind. `<iostream>` is a C++ header, the rest are C headers. What is `<malloc.c>`? Usually, `malloc` should be in `<stdlib.h>` or `<windows.h>`. For this example, you just need `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.

If I switch on compiler warnings, I get the warnings about comparing and assignig integers to pointers. In `delqatend` you should return plain `0` as error code, not `NULL`. likewise here:

```
i = delqatbeg(&a);
if (i != NULL) 
    printf("item deleted from front:%d", i);
```

The `NULL`should be `0`. (`0` is a language representation of the null pointer as well as of null integers, but the macro `NULL` casts it to `(void *)`, making it a pointer. here' `i` is an integer.) Also, please print a newline at the end of the string.

```
temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if (temp == NULL)
    printf("queue is full\n");
```

I like how the queue is full if your job is out of memory, but you shouldn't just print that but do domething else like aborting the process or returning an error code, otherwise you'll do something bad later on in the function to a `NULL` pointer.

Okay, now to your main problem. Let's look at your function `addqatbeg`. In the case where the queue is empty you insert the node correctly, although you essentially do the same assignment twice, because `q->front` and `q->end` are equal. But you don't assign the data to the new node.

The other case, where there is already a node in the queue, is a mess. You don't isert nodes by jiggling around their data, but by reornagising the queue structure through the pointers. Here's a better `addqatbeg`:

```
//add at the beginning of the queue
void addqatbeg(struct queue *q, int item)
{
    struct node *temp;

    // Create node and check for NULL
    temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("queue is full\n");
        return;
    }

    // Assign data
    temp->data = item;
    temp->prev = temp->next = NULL;

    // Insert node
    if (q->front == NULL) {
        q->rear = q->front = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = q->front;
        q->front->prev = temp;
        q->front = temp;
    }
}
```

It should be easy to implement `addqatend` now. The functions `addqatend` and `addqatbeg` are totally analogous in your case, bacause you maintain forward and backward pointers. The `while` loop in your `addqatend` is superflous and introduces an endless loop: You check `q->front`, but never update it in your loop.

Comment: FWIW, you can reduce your add by (1) always setting `temp->next = q->front;` *before* your if-else rather than initializing it to NULL. If the queue is empty, `q->front` will be NULL anyway. Then (2) move the `q->front = temp;` duplicate line *out* of the two logical blocks and rather *always* do it after the if-else. (and +1 on the answer, though I would prefer if you lost the cast of the `malloc()` result if this is supposed to be C-code)

Comment: There's always room for improvenemt. With regard to the cast on `malloc`: The code is essentially C, so it should be removed. But considering that the OP included `<iostream>` I reckoned that he would use a C++ compiler to compile it, which means the cast is probably needed, and decided to leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

Look if these functions work for you. Repeating patterns suggest some refactoring in common functions, but try this out.

Addqatbeg:

```
//add at the beginning of the queue
void addqatbeg(struct queue *q,int item)
{
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(temp == NULL)
    printf("queue is full\n"); 

if(q->front == NULL)
{
    q->rear = q->front = temp;
    q->front->data = item;      
    return;
}
q->front->next = temp;
q->front = q->front->next;
q->front->data = item;    
}
```

Addqatend:

```
//add at the end of the queue
void addqatend(struct queue *q, int item)
{
struct node *temp;
temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(temp == NULL)
    printf("queue is full\n"); 

if(q->rear == NULL)
{
    q->rear = q->front = temp;
    q->rear->data = item;  
    return;
}
q->rear->prev = temp;    
q->rear = q->rear->prev;
q->rear->data = item;    
}
```

Delqatbeg:

```
//delete at the beginning of the queue
int delqatbeg(struct queue *q)
{
struct node *temp;
int item;

if(q->front == NULL)
{
    printf("queue is empty:\n");
    return NULL;
}

item = q->front->data;
    temp = q->front;
    q->front = q->front->prev;        
    free(temp);
}    
return item;
}
```

Delqatend:

```
//delete at the beginning of the queue
int delqatend(struct queue *q)
{
struct node *temp;
int item;

if(q->rear == NULL)
{
    printf("queue is empty:\n");
    return NULL;
}

    item = q->rear->data;
    temp = q->rear;
    q->rear = q->rear->next;        
    free(temp);
return item;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually compiled the code? With compiler warnings? And then checked it? (Hint: it doesn't compile, there's a stray `}` in `delqatbeg`. Hint II: There are compiler warnings about inconsistencies between ints and pointers. Hint III: It doesn't work as intended.) Before thinking about refactoring you should try to get your code right. After all insertions and deletions, the `front`, `rear`, `next` and `prev` pointers in the deque must be consistent.

Comment: I read his code and rewrote it at the post itself. Will follow your Hints.